# What is the unit of the font size in html string?

Tags: android, string

If I use a `<font size='5'>abc</font>` tag in `strings.xml` and render it as Html later on using `Html.fromHtml()`, what is the font size unit of 'abc'? Is it 5 px or 5 sp? How can declare it to use `sp`? Is `sp` supported on the font tag? I'm planning to delare it like this `<font size='5sp'>abc</font>`. Will it work?

Answer (score 2):

The `size` attribute will be ignored on several android versions and you should avoid it.

Instead, use `<h1>`, `<h2>`, ... tags to increase the text size : `<h1>abc</h1>` or `<small>abc</small>` to make the text smaller. It's not really flexible, but `Html.fromHtml()` isn't a real HTML parser and handles only a very limited set of tags.